# Componentwise absolute continuity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, absolute-continuity

It is clear that if $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is an absolutely continuous random vector, then $X_i$ is absolutely continuous for all $i$.

> Is the converse true?

**What I know**

- $\mathbf{X}$ is absolutely continuous if and only if $P(\mathbf{X}\in A)=0$ for all borel set $A$ of measure $0$.
- $\mathbf{X}$ is absolutely continuous if and only if there is a function $f$ such that $P(\mathbf{X}\in A)=\int_{A}f$.
- It's obvious if $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are independent.

Any idea/reference for a proof of this result?

Comment: Yes, just use the $l_\infty$ norm. Then convergence is equivalent to componentwise convergence.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not seeing exactly how can I use convergence results here.

Comment: What is your question? You seem to have asked if the converse is true. What has convergence got to do with that?

Comment: Yes, I've asked that. I'm really new into probability theory, so I only know two different ways to prove that a random vector is abs. cont. One of the is to prove that the induced measure is abs. cont. with respect to Lebesgue's measure. The other is to prove that the induced measure has a density function. Both of them are equivalent thanks to the Radon-Nikodym theorem, but I don't see how convergence issues can help here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converse is absolutely not true. Let $X$ be any absolutely continuous random variable. Then the random vector $(X,X)$ is not absolutely continuous, even though its components are. Indeed, letting $A$ be the set of points on the lines $y=x$, then $P\big((X,X)\in A\big )=1$, even though $A$ is a set with Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: In general, properties of the marginal dsitributions do not tell you much about the joint distribution.